Missing badges?
I am missing the Nice Answer and Enlightened badges for this answer. The minimum vote tally and the acceptance came in weeks ago.
Is anyone else missing a badge? I may have to raise this on Meta SO.

also you would not get enlightened for that since your answer was not the first answer on the question, according to the timestamps I see there. Other answers were provided before yours.

@Jeff "First" refers to time stamps? I had always thought it meant it the initial answer I gave to a question. Thanks for the clarification.

Bear in mind that badge tallies are based on what you should have, and we (almost) never take badges away.
Thus, if a question was deleted that you got a badge for, you now have an "extra" badge. 
This means you will not get another badge of that type until you catch up in absolute counts.

I think I know what's going on. I got a "Nice Answer" for a question that had been voted-up during an early round of shenanigans. That 10th vote was unwound, leaving that answer with 9 votes, but the badge remained.

Should have a badge for "recruiting" other users. I'm not sure if measuring recruitment is possible with the platform, but we have reached a stage where we have questions that need answers and user participation from a broader set than the existing community. 

We have Announcer/Booster/Publicist badges for link referrals. You can post open questions to your favourite social media site in the hopes of getting some responses.

My suggestion is having a badge for acquiring actual "users". For example, I joined the site because a colleague told me about the stack overflow rather than clicking on a link from a booster. (Naturally, there is some # of impressions that corresponds to users but why not reward the objective directly.)

Hmm, that could be an interesting idea. Post it as a question on the main Meta and see how others respond.

This idea has already been proposed on MSO.

I'm missing the beta badge on the main QF site. I guess I shouldn't have given a bounty that dropped me below 100 that first week. 

I'm not sure what the criteria are, but this user has the Beta badge and only has 71 rep points.

@chrisaycock, it used to be 3 badges of any kind by the end of the week. But for some reason I never got the beta badge for QF.

if that's indeed the rule, then you're not alone. I did not receive a beta badge either (on main nor meta). Maybe @Jeff will be able to shed some light on this.

Apropos missing badges, I've just lost my 70 consecutive days streak on main site (all SE addicts reunite ;-)).
What's the activity limit to count as a visit? I remember checking the main page and profile/inbox on my mobile, but it did not register. I will start from zero if it has to be, but if I could ask a favour from some diamond mod I would appreciate telling me what's showing in my login history for 2011-05-08 (UTC)? Thanks.

I see an absence on 2011-05-08.

Thank you. I supposed that would be the case as I'm not seeing it in the calendar despite having visited the site. Weird, maybe it's another obscure bug or some unlucky coincidence (though hitting offline cache only seems highly unlikely) - only SE team could verify that. Never mind, back to day 1, so you've got a bit of a head start. :-)

This was an old bug, the way we hand out badges changed a few months ago. You now have the badge in questions. 
